# Tabularx line break with long space between words

Tags: tabularx

I'm a problem when using the package `tabularx`.

Here is how I use the table:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[margin=3.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\noindent \begin{tabular}[H]{|l|c|c|c|}
\hline
Simple text & A simple long text maybe very long or not i dont know c: & Simple text & Another simple long text maybe very long or not i dont know c:\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\bigskip
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|X|X|X|}
\hline
Simple text & A simple long text maybe very long or not i dont know c: & Simple text & Another simple long text maybe very long or not i dont know c:\\

\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

I was using the the regular taular but I need to have auto linebreak. I get theses long space when he breaks line. How can I have normal space ?

[image]

Thanks in advance,
MYT.

**SOLUTION by leandriis**
The 'long spaces' are due to X columns being based on justified p columns. To get rid of them you could define your own column type as follows:
`\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}`

Comment: The 'long spaces' are due to `X` columns being based on justified `p` columns. To get rid of them you could define your own column type as follows: `\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}`. I don't understand the part about the margin. If I use your MWE, the table spreads from the left to the right margin as expected. You can check that by including `\usepackage{showframe}`.

Comment: I eddited my post, I don't have problem with margin, it's just when I did the two table, I thought I had a problem with margin.  Thank you , your solution works perfectly

Comment: please do not edit the solution in to the question, it makes a mess of the question/answer format. You can post a solution as an _answer_.  Also what is the intention of `\begin{tabular}[H]`  tabular does not have an H option (it just ignores unknown options rather than give an error)

Comment: That's because I used it on the regular tabular, I didn't think to delete it